# Solving cubic equation with unknown coefficients

Tags: equation-solving, broken-code

I am trying to solve a cubic equation with unknown coefficients (`p` and `t`), here is the code:

```
Rgas = 8.314; (* gas constant *)
acoef[tc_, pc_] := (27*Rgas^2*tc^2)/(64*pc);
bcoef[tc_, pc_] := (Rgas*tc)/(8*pc);
latentK = 76.9*10^3*39*1.67*10^-27*6.022*10^23;
tcK = 2223; (* Kelvin *)
pcK = 16*10^6; (*Pa *)
roots = v /. 
  NSolve[(p - Rgas*t)*v^3 - bcoef[tcK, pcK]*p*v^2 + acoef[tcK, pcK]*v 
   - acoef[tcK, pcK]*bcoef[tcK, pcK] == 0, v] // Chop;
test = roots[[1]]
(p - Rgas*t)*test^3 - bcoef[tcK, pcK]*p*test^2 + acoef[tcK, pcK]*test 
  - acoef[tcK, pcK]*bcoef[tcK, pcK] // Chop
```

1) I had to use `NSolve[]` because otherwise it said it did not have exact expressions. I tried to play around with `Rationalize[]`, in vain. Is there any chance of finding an exact solution (i.e. using `Solve[]`) even if the coefficients (p and t) are not known?

2) In the last lines, I am plugging one of the roots (they are all the same) back into the equation, to see if it yields $0$. And it doesn't. Why?  What am I doing wrong? `Chop[]`?

Comment: This is the van der Waals equation, I take it? What are you solving for, critical volume?

Comment: I am solving for the volume, in terms of pressure and temperature. Critical pressure and critical temperature enter the formulae for the coeffcients,a and b (that I've called acoef and bcoef).

Comment: Then, might I suggest reformulating the cubic to be in terms of the compressibility factor $Z=\frac{PV}{RT}$, and solving for $Z$ instead?

Comment: but $Z$ would not incorporate all $V$ factors...? For example, the $\frac{-bP}{RT}$ term would be written $\frac{-bZ}{V}$

Comment: $Z=\cfrac1{1-\cfrac{bP}{ZRT}}-\cfrac{aP}{(RT)^2 Z}$. I trust that you can figure out where this came from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you clear the definition of `Rgas` then `Solve` will work

```
acoef[tc_, pc_] := (27*Rgas^2*tc^2)/(64*pc);
bcoef[tc_, pc_] := (Rgas*tc)/(8*pc);
latentK = 76.9*10^3*39*1.67*10^-27*6.022*10^23;
tcK = 2223;(*Kelvin*)
pcK = 16*10^6;(*Pa*)

eqn = (p - Rgas*t)*v^3 - bcoef[tcK, pcK]*p*v^2 + acoef[tcK, pcK]*v - 
   acoef[tcK, pcK]*bcoef[tcK, pcK];
asolns = Solve[eqn == 0, v]
```

[image]

And you can plug this back into your equation,

```
(eqn /. asolns)[[1]]
```

[image]

which looks pretty hairy - and maybe some combination of `Simplify` and `ComplexExpand` would show it to be zero, but I'm too lazy for that.  I just test it with some numbers

```
% /. {Rgas -> 8.314, p -> 1, t -> 100}
(* 3.33067*10^-16 - 6.2626*10^-16 I *)
```

There's no reason not to use `NSolve` if you have `Rgas` defined as a real number in decimal format.

```
Rgas = 8.314;
solns = NSolve[eqn == 0, v];
test = (v /. solns)[[1]] // Chop
eqn /. v -> test
```

[image]

And then you put in values for `p` and `t` to see if it is zero,

```
% /. {Rgas -> 8.314, p -> 1, t -> 100}
(* -0.001301 *)
```

That didn't work.  As you suspect, it was the `Chop` that messed you up,

```
test = (v /. solns)[[1]];
answer = eqn /. v -> test;
answer /. {Rgas -> 8.314, p -> 1, t -> 100}
(* 1.22791*10^-16 - 1.38741*10^-14 I *)
```

So I don't think you'll get a pretty, one-page solution to this equation, but the numerical one works as long as you don't apply `Chop` until you've put in values for all the variables.

Comment: As I recall, for my thesis, I broke down and used `Root[]` instead to represent the roots of the van der Waals equation, since the full symbolic form was too unwieldy to be practical.

Comment: As a continuation, I now would like to use the real root (in terms of p and t) in a differnetial equation, to be solved numerically.
Basically i would want dp/dt = const/realroot, where realroot = v /. asolns[[1]].
Do I somehow have to change realroot to be a function of p[t] and t?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following: first solve exactly the cubic equation:

```
sl = Solve[a*v^3 - b*v^2 + c*v + d == 0, v]
```

The returned result is long and, therefore, I do not write it here. Get it by evaluating the code above. Then this

```
 Rgas = 8.314;(*gas constant*)
acoef[tc_, pc_] := (27*Rgas^2*tc^2)/(64*pc);
bcoef[tc_, pc_] := (Rgas*tc)/(8*pc);
latentK = 76.9*10^3*39*1.67*10^-27*6.022*10^23;
tcK = 2223;(*Kelvin*)pcK = 16*10^6;(*Pa*)

sl[[1, 1, 2]] /. {a -> (p - Rgas*t), b -> bcoef[tcK, pcK]*p, 
  c -> acoef[tcK, pcK], d -> -acoef[tcK, pcK]*bcoef[tcK, pcK]}
```

gives you your result, for example, for the first of the three roots, also rather long. Be aware that I did not check, if the solution is real, do it yourself.

```
(*
(0.0000481303 p)/(
 p - 8.314 t) - (2^(
    1/3) (-2.08487*10^-8 p^2 + 
      27.0199 (p - 8.314 t)))/(3 (6.02072*10^-12 p^3 + Sqrt[
      4 (-2.08487*10^-8 p^2 + 
          27.0199 (p - 8.314 t))^3 + (6.02072*10^-12 p^3 - 
         0.0117043 p (p - 8.314 t) + 0.0351128 (p - 8.314 t)^2)^2] - 
      0.0117043 p (p - 8.314 t) + 0.0351128 (p - 8.314 t)^2)^(
    1/3) (p - 8.314 t)) + (1/(
 3 2^(1/3) (p - 8.314 t)))((6.02072*10^-12 p^3 + Sqrt[
   4 (-2.08487*10^-8 p^2 + 
       27.0199 (p - 8.314 t))^3 + (6.02072*10^-12 p^3 - 
      0.0117043 p (p - 8.314 t) + 0.0351128 (p - 8.314 t)^2)^2] - 
   0.0117043 p (p - 8.314 t) + 0.0351128 (p - 8.314 t)^2)^(1/3))
*)
```

Have fun!

Comment: thanks, why is there only one root though? Shouldn't there be 3?

Comment: @Super, yes, there should be three, but in this case, you'll have either one real root (full vapor case) or three real roots (where only the two extreme roots have any physical meaning).

Comment: @SuperCiocia It is only an example to show you, how to calculate. All the rest you can do yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Using [`Rationalize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html)

```
Clear[p, t, v];
Rgas = 8.314 // Rationalize;(*gas constant*)
acoef[tc_, pc_] := (27*Rgas^2*tc^2)/(64*pc);
bcoef[tc_, pc_] := (Rgas*tc)/(8*pc);
latentK = 769*10^2*39*167*10^-29*6022*10^20;
(* Note that you do not use latentK *)
tcK = 2223;(*Kelvin*)
pcK = 
 16*10^6;(*Pa*)

eqn = (p - Rgas*t)*v^3 - bcoef[tcK, pcK]*p*v^2 + acoef[tcK, pcK]*v - 
    acoef[tcK, pcK]*bcoef[tcK, pcK] == 0;

soln = Solve[eqn, v] // Simplify;
```

Verifying that `soln` satisfies `eqn`

```
And @@ (eqn /. soln // Simplify)

(*  True  *)

roots = v /. soln;
(*  long result  *)
```

Only the first root is real (for appropriate values of `p` and `t`)

```
fd = FunctionDomain[#, {p, t}] & /@ roots
```

[image]

```
Reduce[fd[[1]], {p, t}, Reals] // Simplify
```

[image]